# Unit shutdown.service could not be found

Tags: service, daemon, startup, systemctl, shutdown

I'm trying to set up in a Redhat server, 2 services that start a database at startup, and stop it at shutdown, so I have put 2 files under `/etc/systemd/system` as follows:

shutdown.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown database at shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/DBA/shutdown.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

startup service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start   database at startup after network becomes reachable
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/DBA/startup.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

then I did these commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable startup.service
sudo systemctl enable shutdown.service
sudo systemctl start startup.service
sudo systemctl start shutdown.service
```

then when I look at the status, they work fine and show active and running. I then reboot the server, and I check again the status but I get this:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-193-117-56 system]$ sudo systemctl status shutdown.service
Unit shutdown.service could not be found.
[ec2-user@ip-10-193-117-56 system]$ sudo systemctl status startup.service
Unit startup.service could not be found.
[ec2-user@ip-10-193-117-56 system]$
```

So I don't understand, what is the issue. Why the services aren't being found after rebooting the server ? they are supposed to be enabled and started once, then they should start automatically.

Any idea ?

Here are both services inside the folder:

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
ls -l
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root  246 Feb 22 16:02  startup.service
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root root  255 Feb 22 16:02  shutdown.service
```

Comment: Why the shutdown "service"? Why don't you just define shutdown and start in one service unit?

Comment: what do you mean ? they are not triggered by the same triggers. that's not the question here.

Comment: You don't need two service definitions to start and stop a service. Both should be handled by the same unit file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue is to disable SELinux feature by doing the following ( permanent disabling) :

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Then change the directive `SELinux=enforcing` to `SELinux=disabled`

Reboot then : `sestatus`, it should now show it is disabled.

Comment: Disabling selinux is not a solution. Create a selinux module to allow what you need to do instead.